# Change user and home folder name of own account and now can't unlock admin rights

Tags: macos, administrator, root, macos-sierra, macos-highsierra

This are the instructions for changing the user and home folder:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548#shortname

I didn't follow this warning:

> The administrator account needs to be a different account than the one you're renaming. If necessary, create another administrator account, then remove it when you're done.

Now when I try to unlock admin right on the preferences pane it asks for:

[image]

And nothing seems to work.

I know the password for sure since I can login.

I have done `ls /Users` and can see what should be my old user and that doesn't work, neither does what I set, how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you since created the second Administrator account?

Comment: @Ramhound how so? I need to login as admin to do so AFAIK.

Comment: You indicated that is possible,  **"I know the password for sure since I can login."**, so have you created that second user?

Comment: @Ramhound can login to osx, but I can't unlock admin rights inside preferences.

Comment: I assume you can't use root in case like this?

Comment: @Ramhound how so? from the terminal?

Comment: [You can indeed create the new user in a terminal.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4814/can-user-accounts-be-managed-via-the-command-line) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226073/how-do-i-create-user-accounts-from-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x-10-11)

Comment: You can only create a new user from terminal if you have sudo... which you likely don't. Alternative is to delete AppleSetupDone - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac Make a new admin account, use that to fix the old one.

Comment: @Tetsujin that worked, thank you very much! Do you wanna post it as an answer?

Comment: Done. Marked it as community, as it wasn't really my answer. Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit for this goes to [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside) from [Ask Different - I don't have administrator account on my mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac)

> You can create a new administrator account by restarting the Setup
>   Assistant:
>
> 1. Boot into Single User Mode <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.
> 2. Mount the drive by typing `/sbin/mount -uw /` then <kbd>↩ enter</kbd>.
> 3. Remove the Apple Setup Done file by typing `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` then <kbd>↩ enter</kbd>.
> 4. Reboot by typing `reboot` then <kbd>↩ enter</kbd>.
> 5. Complete the setup process, creating a new admin account.

Once you have a new admin account, you can use it to fix your old one, delete afterwards if no longer required.